# Cache in Laravel using Redis

Tags: laravel, session, caching, redis

I build the app in laravel, In which I used Redis for cache. Success to store in cache but problem is that, I run app in one browser and do login success and store cache, now in another browser it will automatically login.

I use code for store and load cache

```
if(Cache::has('mykey'))
{
    return Cache::get('mykey');
}
else
{
    // Do some operation and store it in cache
    Cache::put('mykey',content,10);
    // and then return
}
```

Please tell me what is wrong...
thanks in advance

Comment: You need to use session cache, not file cache to seperate client cache.

Comment: The cache is always the same for everyone visiting your website. I think what you need is a [session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session).

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
// Check cache first
$catchPage = Cache::get('mykey');
if ($catchPage != null) {
    return $catchPage;
}
else {
    Cache::tags('tag_name')->put('mykey',$content,10);
    // and then return
}
```

Taken reference from [here](https://tuts.codingo.me/improve-site-loading-speed-using-redis).

**As per [laravel 5.3 Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/cache)**:
You may access various cache stores via the store method.

The key passed to the store method should correspond to one of the stores listed in the stores configuration array in your cache configuration file:

```
$value = Cache::store('file')->get('foo');

Cache::store('redis')->put('bar', 'baz', 10);
```

If you need to retrieve an item from the cache and then delete the item, you may use the pull method. Like the *get* method, *null* will be returned if the item does not exist in the cache:

```
$value = Cache::pull('key');
```

The *add* method will only add the item to the cache if it does not already exist in the cache store. The method will return *true* if the item is actually added to the cache. Otherwise, the method will *return* false:

```
Cache::add('key', 'value', $minutes);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd

Comment: Not at all i'll try as per your solution..
as you told add and pull method is there any method for edit value @ AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd

Comment: @Ravi9994: As per my knowledge, there is not concept to edit cache. So regenerate the same.